# iid and correlated order statistics a comparison

Tags: probability, statistics, order-statistics

Consider the two random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ defined via i.i.d, non-negative random variables $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ as

$ X_1=\min(Y_1,Y_2)\\$

$ X_2=\min(Y_1,Y_1)$  -  (maximally correlated)

The question is can we say $X_1 \leq X_2$ always? How to prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have written the question correctly, then $X_2=Y_1$ (minimum of two functions is the function itself. Remember that random variables are functions).

Then it's always the case that $X_1 \leq X_2$ as just by definition, minimum of two functions is always less than or equal to each of the two functions. Alternatively, $\min(Y_1,Y_2)=\dfrac{Y_1+Y_2-|Y_1-Y_2|}{2}$, and show that this expression is always less than or equal to $Y_1$

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Dr. voldemort. I am still looking for solid probabilistic proof.

Comment: If you know any probabilistic proof for this please let me know or give me a pointer. thanks a lot.

Comment: @Oliver: None that I am aware of. I shall be very interested to see a probabilistic proof. I think of random variables as functions- and so this is the proof I thought of.

Comment: Thank you Sir...Your answer is very helpful indeed. I will try and let you know.

Comment: Glad to help :).

Comment: Thanks Sir..Sir, what do you think $X_1 \leq X_2$ still holds when $X_2=min(Y_1,Y2)$ where $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are correlated and $X_1=min(Y_1,Y2)$ where $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are i.i.d?

Comment: @Oliver: I am not very sure about this question. You may want to ask it as a separate question. I will definitely think about it, and let you know if I get a solution.

Comment: @Oliver It is not clear that your $Y's$ are the same in both cases...it seems they cannot be, so which one is fixed, and which one is allowed to vary in $X_2$.