# iid and correlated order statistics - A comparison

Tags: probability, statistics, order-statistics, independence

This is an extension of my previous question from the post

[iid and correlated order statistics a comparison](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1104855/iid-and-correlated-order-statistics-a-comparison)

Consider the two random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ defined via non-negative random variables $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ as

$ X_1=\min(Y_1,Y_2)\\$  where $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are i.i.d  and

$ X_2=\min(Y_1,Y_2)$  - where $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are correlated.

The question is can we say $X_1 \leq X_2$ always? How to prove it?

Comment: Your X's are defined on different probability spaces; hence, they cannot be compared as formulated. Can you describe how the $Y$ pairs for $X_1$ are related to the $Y$ pairs for $X_2$?